# Require login per controller/view (Angular JS)

Tags: angularjs

Parts of my app require user validation which is done either automatically (using an existing refresh token stored as a cookie) or manually using a login form.

While I can implement this using a Service it feels rather hackish (the various services are designed to return data). But I can't think of a better way to share capabilities between different controllers.

P.S
I did check out https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth but catching the 401 error and initiating a login means that I will make an extra call even though I can tell it will fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can definitely break up the login process into a service, as it can be incredibly important to store and pass info to various controllers in your app, and this is precisely what services are for.

I have created a bug-reporting app using something similar to that link you pointed out, but I customized it using a service and a controller as well.  These are the steps I followed as I set it up:

- First, I set up the interceptor to catch the 401 errors and
  broadcasts a message that login is required.
- I then set up an authService to log all those bad 401 calls.  If
  there is a bad call, it gets stored.
- I also have a login controller that also uses the authService than
  handles the form, registration, login, logout, etc etc.  The
  controller is used in the menu on every page, so there is no chance
  that a broadcast event could be missed.  My controller listens for
  the broadcast event, and when received, displays the login form.
- After a successful login, I tell my authService to repeat all those
  stored calls and delete them.

Now this works great, but what if someone refreshes the page, the authService is deleted, and the interceptor will have to do all the work again, events will need to be broadcast, and ultimately it is a pain.  To overcome this I did a simple check in my login controller.

- First just check to see if the authService has the user object stored.
- If not, do a check with the server, if the result is that the user is logged in, populate the authService again.
- If the user is not logged in, do nothing, but let the authService know that you have checked against the server and seen that the user wasn't logged in.

Again, in my case I didn't want to force users to log in unless they were trying to perform specific actions that required a login.  As a bug-reporting app, I wanted to allow anonymous users to read content, but as soon as they were going to post they had to register or login.

If your case involves being logged in 100% of the time, you can completely ignore the interceptor.  Just set up a service and a controller.  If the login controller sees that the authService isn't populated, redirect to the login screen.  Upon refresh, do a simple check against the server to ensure they are still logged in, otherwise redirect to the login screen.

Comment: Thanks, I was slowly working my way towards a similar solution but this will save me quite a bit of time.

Answer (score 3):

A service is very appropriate in this case.  As described in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY) about best practices,  Services aren't as much about "Getting data", as it is separation of logic from the controller.  A controller says what to do, a service says how to do it.

So, in your case, a Controller says "I need to check if the user is authenticated" but to know how to do that, it depends on a service.

This fits perfectly with the data-gathering concept as well.  A controller says "I need to get all of the Employee Information."  The service defines how.

He specifically says in this meeting that whenever there is information that needs to be shared between controllers, a service is pretty much always the best way to do it.